# regarding a shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I happen need to use the following shell script

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c '
mv "$0" "${0%/*}/$(printf "%s\n" "${0##*/}" | sha1sum | cut -d" " -f1)"
' {} \;
```

But I do not understand how does this script work? For instance, how to analyze

```
mv "$0" "${0%/*}/$(printf "%s\n" "${0##*/}" | sha1sum | cut -d" " -f1)"
' {} \;
```

piece by piece? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printf "%s\n" "${0##*/}"
```

`${0##*/}` takes the path `$0` and strips off any leading directory names, leaving only the file name. The printf command adds a newline to the end and then this file name is piped to...

```
| sha1sum | cut -d" " -f1
```

This computes the SHA-1 hash of the file name and then uses `cut` to extract just the hash from sha1sum's output.

```
${0%/*}
```

This is the opposite of `${0##*/}`—this one gets the directories from `$0` and throws away the file name.

So effectively, what ends up getting run is:

```
mv "$DIR/$FILENAME" "$DIR/$HASH_OF_FILENAME"
```

In English, it renames every file it finds to the SHA-1 hash of the original file name.

---

For what it's worth, it could be simplified a bit and made more readable. I might write the mv command as:

```
mv "$0" "$(dirname "$0")/$(basename "$0" | sha1sum | awk "{print \$1}")
```